# Is there a way to use loop and array in this access vba sub to toggle command button view

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am using this sub to toggle view of command button in access form. But I want to do it using a loop and array of optional command buttons as argument,  as number of buttons will eventually increase

```
enter code here 

Public Sub toggleView(x As Boolean, ByVal a As CommandButton, _
 Optional ByVal b As CommandButton, Optional ByVal c As CommandButton, _
   Optional ByVal d As CommandButton)

    a.Visible = x
    b.Visible = x
    c.Visible = x
    d.Visible = x

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [ParamArray](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-parameter-arrays) like this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Command1_Click()
   ToggleView False, Command2, Command3, Command4
End Sub

Private Sub ToggleView(x As Boolean, ParamArray buttons() As Variant)
   Dim i As Integer

   For i = LBound(buttons) To UBound(buttons)
      buttons(i).Visible = x
   Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like so.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Click()

Dim a() As CommandButton
ReDim a(2)
Set a(0) = Me.CommandButton1
Set a(1) = Me.CommandButton2
Set a(2) = Me.CommandButton3

ButtonSub a

End Sub

Function ButtonSub(arr() As MSForms.CommandButton)


End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to use the .Tag property of the control. For each control that you want to toggle the visibility of, set the .Tag property to "Toggle", and then modify your code to be:

```
Public Sub toggleView(x As Boolean)
    Dim ctl As Control
    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        If ctl.Tag = "Toggle" Then
            ctl.Visible = x
        End If
    Next ctl
End Sub
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

you could loop through userform controls and act on `CommandButton` type ones only

```
Public Sub toggleView(x As Boolean)
    Dim ctl As Control
    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(ctl) = "CommandButton" Then ctl.Visible = x
    Next
End Sub
```